# Is it possible to make concept of room in websockets?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

Does Websocket supports room?
I need a room based chat app, in Websocket but there I cant see any options for creating room as socket.io supports creating room and namespace.

If Websocket does not support, is there any alternative concept for room with websocket?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Socket.io` for namespaces and rooms creation.

Reference:

1. https://socket.io/docs/#Restricting-yourself-to-a-namespace
2. https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/